# Are there any VST audio to MIDI plugins?

Tags: vst, analysis

In Pure Data / MAX/MSP etc. there's are objects that can take in an audio signal and output a control signal with the frequency. (So you can whistle a tune into the mic and have a synth play it.)

Are there any VST plugins that do something similar? For use in, say, FL Studio?

I see plenty of spectrum analyser plugins for visualizing frequencies. But any that turn them into control signals?

Comment: I once programmed [something like that](https://youtu.be/T9jd_PXkdEI?t=8m36s) in SynthMaker, but never really make it a proper plugin. Would that be any use to you?

Comment: Good question. You could probably build something capable of doing this in Reaktor.

Comment: @leftaroundabout That's really cool. Yeah, if it's available to download somewhere, I'd love to have a play. I haven't really looked into Flowstone. And I didn't realize you could write your own scripts. Awesome!

Comment: @leftaroundabout It would be really interesting to see if [it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9jd_PXkdEI&feature=youtu.be&t=8m36s) works with a more complicated wave, like a whistle.

Answer (score 4):

[Audio To Midi](http://www.mindthepressure.org/plugz.php) - Free plugin by Mind The Pressure.  Translates audio to midi signal directly so it can be hooked up with any virtual instrument ([direct download](http://www.mindthepressure.org/plugz/audiotomidi.zip))

[WIDI Audio to MIDI](http://www.widisoft.com/english/mp3-midi-products.html) - Not free. Somewhat similar to the above, but it has some stability problems.

Comment: Added another "Audio To Midi" which seem more like it.. check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DtMJTxX4WA&list=RD4DtMJTxX4WA

Comment: Mind the Pressure also has a dope website...woah!